# Django : Is it better to set PostgreSQL as database from the start of project?

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, django-database

I just wonder whether I start with `PostgreSQL` or `sqlite3` when starting `Django` project.

I usually start with `sqlite3`, which is a default database, and change it into `PostgreSQL` at the time to deploy.

I use `TDD` and heard that it is much faster when use `PostgreSQL` as a database.
Is it right? If so, do I have to use `PostgreSQL` from the start?

Need some advices. Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of differences between databases that ORMs rarely protect you from (case sensitivity of LIKE, GROUP BY behavior, `varchar(n)` size handling, date/time functions, column types, ...). You should develop, test, and deploy on the same stack IMO.

Comment: I agree with @muistooshort. I don't know that TDD is faster with PostgreSQL, but you really need to test what you intend to deploy. If you're deploying to PostgreSQL, you need to test under PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really say that PostgreSQL is faster. If you don't have a complex DB schema and/or a lot of models, sqlite may probably be a lot faster, since it will be run in-memory when running tests.

However, if you have complex schema and a lot of migrations - PostgreSQL and `--keepdb` flag would be better. However, do remember that that way your database still exists after running the tests.